# Why are my dynamic text fields not populating?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For some reason my dynamic text fields aren't populating anymore. The only new thing I added before it stopped working correctly was a new button, but either way..if I take the button out or not, no text field is populating. This is on all the layers I have. If I change the font of the text fields, they start populating correctly..and when I make all of them the same font..they start not populating anymore!

Comment: Are you embedding those fonts?

Comment: Even if I do, they don't show up at all

Comment: Try creating a new document and copy your assets there. Sometimes Flash acts weird and recreating the document solves it.

Comment: Are they not populating? Or just not showing? Do some traceing / debugging on the content of the field to see what they are. This will confirm whether or not this is a rendering issue (most likely from fonts) or if you have inadvertently introduced a bug somewhere.